# POWER BI how to compare two data

Tags: powerbi

Thank you for you help in advance. I tried to find the same issue online I was unable. I am trying to use Power BI to compare set of data and to make my life easier every time a check data for submissions.

I am going to sum up the issue. If I have a master table with all the data and them all the data produced by my workers, how I can I compare them against the master table? See example below

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

You are asking the question wrong, or asking the wrong question. "How can I compare  ...?" is too broad.

What insights do you want to derive from the data?  You need to be more specific, like, "How many workers have Product A in yellow and size L?"  or  something like that. Then you can start building a data model that helps you get these insights.

The first step will be to consolidate the worker data into one table instead of a table for each worker. Add a column for Worker Name and combine them all into one.

Now you can build charts and pivots for aspects of the worker data and also do the same for the master data for comparison.

Comment: Hi, thank you for you quick response.  I guess I am asking the question wrong them. That was an example. Call it storehouse or production lines. The point is that I need to be able to check what I got in the tables below against the master data. A product called "A" has to be "Red" and size "S". I need to be able to compare  all data sets against this masterdata. Does it make more sense now? Thank you for you answer

Comment: Why would you want to use Power BI for that? That is totally not what it is for.

Comment: Also, how would the "comparison" look like? Power BI has tables and charts. What exactly would you want to see?? Can you mock something up manually to give us something to aim for?

Comment: I need to generate reports automatically. I know it can be done because our client is doing it.What I want to avoid is our client telling is all wrong and doing "if" and "vlookup" in excel is not going to user friendly to read for our people generating that information. So following the example above, I need to be able to look at the info from user A check it against the master data and say, product A colour and size are correct, product B colour and size are wrong, etc.

Comment: Hi, I guess I go sort of the answer I needed.  New colunm ->   Column1 Check = IF(CONTAINS('Masterdata','Masterdata'[Colour],'Worker 1'[Colour]),1,0). Using this I can compare the data and list errors and rights. Thank you for your time!